Cannot Install mpi4py with pip - Building wheel failed
I have heard that there have been issues installing this package with Python 3.9 or higher (mine is 3.11.4), but I'm wondering if there is a workaround.
I ran:
python3 -m pip install mpi4py

and got:
Collecting mpi4py
  Using cached mpi4py-3.1.5.tar.gz (2.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mpi4py
  Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [156 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_src
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/dl.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/libmpi.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      running build_clib
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      MPI C compiler:    /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
      MPI C++ compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
      MPI F compiler:    /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpifort
      MPI F90 compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpif90
      MPI F77 compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpif77
      checking for library 'lmpe' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'mpe' dylib library
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lib-pmpi
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/mpe.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lib-pmpi/mpe.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "mpe" failed
      
      checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt' dylib library
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lib-pmpi/vt.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt" failed
      
      checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt-mpi' dylib library
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-mpi" failed
      
      checking for library 'vt-hyb' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.ompi' ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt-hyb' dylib library
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-hyb" failed
      
      running build_ext
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      MPI C compiler:    /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
      MPI C++ compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
      MPI F compiler:    /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpifort
      MPI F90 compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpif90
      MPI F77 compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpif77
      checking for dlopen() availability ...
      checking for header 'dlfcn.h' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      success!
      checking for library 'dl' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311 -ldl -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
      checking for function 'dlopen' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311 -ldl -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
      building 'mpi4py.dl' extension
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DHAVE_DLOPEN=1 -I/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c src/dynload.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/dynload.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -shared -Wl,-rpath,/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib -L/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib -L/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/dynload.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311 -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/dl.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      checking for MPI compile and link ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

After the basic pip install command failed, I ran the following:
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py

and got the following error message:
Collecting git+https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py
  Cloning https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py to /tmp/pip-req-build-znv_wkdi
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py /tmp/pip-req-build-znv_wkdi
  Resolved https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py to commit d99274629cefe96352cd4b5c4abf1ad7c550bfab
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mpi4py
  Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [90 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_src
      using Cython 3.0.10
      cythonizing 'src/mpi4py/MPI.pyx' -> 'src/mpi4py/MPI.c'
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/typing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/typing.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/libmpi.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/util.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/util.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/mpi4py/util
      running build_ext
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      MPI C compiler:    /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
      MPI C++ compiler:  /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
      checking for MPI compile and link ...
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include -fPIC -I/home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /home/hgc-swin/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 330: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
      Installing mpi4py requires a working MPI implementation.
      If you are running on a supercomputer or cluster, check with
      the system administrator or refer to the system user guide.
      Otherwise, if you are running on a laptop or desktop computer,
      your may be missing the MPICH or Open MPI development package:
      * On Fedora/RHE

L systems, run:
        $ sudo dnf install mpich-devel     # for MPICH
        $ sudo dnf install openmpi-devel   # for Open MPI
      * On Debian/Ubuntu systems, run:
        $ sudo apt install libmpich-dev    # for MPICH
        $ sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev  # for Open MPI
      [end of output]



  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I also tried running with conda, but was warned that this could break some of my other conda installations, and I didn't want to run that risk.
Any suggestions welcome!

You should show how the regular pip command failed. You're now trying to build the package from source, which requires additional dependencies (as the error message is telling you, with instructions).

Okay, you're building from source in both cases. But in any case, since you're in an conda environment (for good or for worse), I think you should try the conda install instructions. Conda environments should be isolated from one another.

OK, now I've installed it with conda, I have a new error.
When I run from mpi4py import MPI, I get:
ImportError: libmpi.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

That library should be provided by mpich or openmpi as described in the install instructions above...

I installed mpi4py using conda-forge with openmpi - it should have worked.
